# How to adjust the spacing of Matplotlib and Seaborn graphics?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm not finding a function or ways to adjust my X axis, which contains many values, I wanted to sort them into a top 10, but I couldn't and the X axis was this mess with the values.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add your code as text, not as an image. Please also add some test data. Don't forget to import all libraries to create executable code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `order=order[:10]` to limit the plot to the 10 highest.
Use `ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=30)` to rotate the ticks to make them easier to read.

Here is some code to test and show how it looks like:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

N = 300
cars = pd.DataFrame({'CarName': [f'name_{n}' for n in np.random.randint(1, 30, N)]})
order = cars['CarName'].value_counts().index
ax = sns.countplot(cars['CarName'], data=cars, palette='rainbow', order=order[:10])
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=30)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]